# Config a short url to an action to work from root url in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a controller that shows item details based on an input parameter, so something like this:

```
mydomain.com/book/detail/3
```

It shows the book with id = 3. Fine!

I would like to shorten the url to this:

```
mydomain.com/3
```

I hope this is possible, but I was not able to set this up. 
I tried to make a custom route in the RouteConfig - RegisterRoutes but had no luck.

Is this possible with a routing rule? Or other solutions?

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a custom route before the default one in `RouteConfig.cs` like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "BookRoute",
            url: "{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Book", action = "Detail"}
        );
```

Comment: Great it works! I was just missing to put it BEFORE the default route. Thank you very much!!

Comment: With welcome! Yes be careful the order matters in the routes list if you add other custom routes.